# jQuery jPaginate - controls are displaying twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

I'm using this plugin called jPaginate.js by [asirokas](https://github.com/asirokas/jPaginate)

But I'm unable to use it twice on a single page. Take a look at the image below

[image]

If i use it twice, the first one gets page controls twice, and is not functional. But the second one gets once and is functional.

js -

```
$(document).ready(function ()
  $('#poppagination').paginate({
    items_per_page: 8,
  });
});
```

I do use different IDs for each pagination. If i use "poppagination" for the first one, i use "poppagination2" for the second one. Don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change IDs without number 1,2 etc... as poppagination and poppaginationTwo

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use two (or more) instances of this plugin because the way it works.